# Compatibility of DDR3 Graphics card to DDR2 RAM

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card

I am trying to install Autocad 2007 in my system ,but it fails. One of system person told me to increase Graphics card.  So I am planning to purchase (online) Galaxy NVIDIA GeForce 210 1 GB DDR3 Graphics Card which is in my range Rs.2000.

My doubt is, will the DDR3 graphics card be supported along with my DDR2 RAM? As I am planning to purchase online, I am worried to place a order.

My system specification is Intel Core2Duo, 2 GB DDR2 RAM.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your  GPU's memory type has got nothing to do with the system memory type. It'll work fine.

On a related note, you'd benefit more from a RAM upgrade than a GPU upgrade.

Comment: @Sathya thanks for valuable comment. When I try to install that software at last moment it fails ( it looks like it almost installed, but unable to load/finish the installation).  Do you think it will be solved by increasing the RAM only ? Or should I purchase Graphics Card ? I can invest either in RAM or in Graphics card ( budget constraint).

Comment: @bholanath I would ask a new question about installing autocad and include all the details I could (especially copy and pasting any error messages it gave me)

Comment: what @ScottC said. It's nearly impossible to deduce anything right now, without the error message listed

Comment: Yes I agree with both of you @Sathya, but the problem is my nephew is installing it in my native place and no internet connection there. What I can do is, I will ask the error messages and try my best to write in a proper sentences. Hope you will be able to help me. I will post it tomorrow. Thanks again to both of you.

Answer (score 2):

It would *absolutely* work. Your video card more often than not uses a different type of ram (GDDRx) from your system anyway.

DDR3 is a lower performing (but cooler running) alternative for GDDR4/5 (or various other numbers) used in passively cooled cards or to cut costs. The DDR3 in this case is used by your GPU not your video card and would work.

I'm running a [gforce 450 varient](http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/ENGTS450_DC_SLDI1GD3/) which uses DDR3 on an older system with ddr2 ram on the main board

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge, the DDR3 graphics card be supported along with my DDR2 RAM but check whether the PCI express slot and SMPS will be supported with your new NVIDIA GeForce 210 1 GB DDR3